# Java is constantly generating an error log in my home directory?

Tags: fedora, logs, java

I have started to notice that whenever I use a Java-based application on Fedora 20, whether it's a game or Eclipse or something else, it will always generate an error log of some sort in home directory.

This is an annoying place for logs to be saved in the first place, but I obviously would like to fix whatever error it is referencing. But I am not quite sure what it is saying or how I would go about fixing this.

The name of the error logs are always `abrt_checker_####.log`, the #### being a series of random numbers.

Below is an example of what one of these error logs look like. So, my question is, **what does this error mean and how I can I fix it?**

```
Uncaught java.lang.ClassNotFoundException exception in thread "main" in a method java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass() with signature (Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class;
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .usr.lib64.eclipse..plugins.org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20131104-1241.jar
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/net/URLClassLoader$1.class]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/net/URLClassLoader$1.class]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/security/AccessController.class]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/net/URLClassLoader.class]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/lang/ClassLoader.class]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader.class]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) [jar:file:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/lang/ClassLoader.class]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try downloading the native JVM and not use IceTea (OpenJDK), which is typically installed by default.  This tutorial titled: [Install Oracle Java JDK/JRE 7u45 on Fedora 20/19, CentOS/RHEL 6.5/5.10](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) discussed how to:

- download
- install
- use alternatives to make it coexist with IceTea (OpenJDK)

Comment: I have already downloaded and installed the RPM file from Oracle for Java, but I presume that I just haven't set it up correctly. Could you explain the third step a bit more?

Comment: The 3rd step is covered in the URL I included. It is a lot of steps that I didn't want to just blindly add to this A unless you deemed it needed. Try them and if they work OK I'll add them here as well (in a condensed form).

Comment: Whoops, I missed the hyperlink in the answer. I followed the instructions there, and it fixed the annoying logs instantly! However, there was one thing that didn't work. Even after installing both the JRE and the JDK, when I ran `alternatives --config libjavaplugin.so.x86_64`, the only option was an IcedTea version. Was this the part that would be used in something like Firefox?

Comment: @jflory7 - yes that one didn't work for me either. I ended up doing this. In this dir: `$HOME/.mozilla/plugins` make this links. `ln -s /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so`. Then restart your browser and it should see the new plugin.